# java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1 in Play 2 project after upgrading to sbt-idea 1.5.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I have been trying to create a Play2 IntelliJ project file using the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin.

I have added the line to my `build.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")
```

However, since updating to the latest version of Play **2.2.1**, I have been seeing the following error when trying to create project files:

```
[error] java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
```

Has anyone else seen this error? It was working fine prior to updating my Play project to 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of IntelliJ IDEA 13 comes with ["The new version of Scala plugin comes with built-in support for SBT"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/) so you should be able to import the project without the plugin's help.

Comment: Many thanks for the update, I will try taking out that line altogether and seeing if IntelliJ is able to generate the project files.

Answer (score 0):

So after an hour or so of looking at colleague's codebases which WERE able to successfully generate the IntelliJ project files, I have updated the plugin details as follows to version 1.5.1 (rather than 1.5.2):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.1")
```

And now it works again as expected. Has anyone else seen this issue with Play 2.2.1 and the plugin https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea ? Is there a better solution, or some other incompatibility I need to resolve?